# Can multiple LANs be configured to work as one when connected together?

Tags: routing, lan, wan

Let's say I have multiple standalone Ethernet networks in a classic NAT configuration. The LANs can be connected together resulting in one big network. What kind of router configuration would enable these networks to function both standalone and connected together?

```
  ┌─────┐     ┌─────┐
  │ WAN │     │ WAN │
  └──┬──┘     └──┬──┘
     │           …
┌────┴────┐ ┌────┴────┐
│ Router? │ │ Router? │
└────┬────┘ └────┬────┘
     │           │
  ┌──┴──┐     ┌──┴──┐
…─┤ LAN ├──…──┤ LAN ├─…
  └─────┘     └─────┘
```

Connecting the networks together should:

- allow typical LAN traffic between the hosts
- enable a host to find a router with a working WAN

Comment: Sadly, classwork and homework questions are off topic here.

Comment: Maybe your comment might be off-topic? My question relates to the planning of a network in a specific enterprise sector. This seems to be [on topic](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site.

Comment: You have bot routers on the same site?

Comment: Yes. In fact they are mobile racks on wheels. This is why they are sometimes connected and sometimes not.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect two LANs via bridge/switch they become one LAN or broadcast domain.

You can run the hosts in different subnets *but* that won't work with the usual DHCP setup - multiple DHCP servers means multiple, conflicting DHCP offers, likely with different subnets. Without further configuration you can expect chaos. Using DHCP snooping to split the shared broadcast domain into two DHCP domains is possible but may not be too practical.

Another problem are multiple gateways that normal hosts cannot handle properly.

Practical approaches include:

- connect networks via routers only, using a link segment/subnet; each router needs to have a static or dynamic route to the LAN behind the other router
- connect networks via bridge/switch but use a single router (or HA cluster) only, connected to both WLAN uplinks; set up some kind of load balancing (by current bandwidth, source address, protocol, ...) or failover concept to utilize both WAN links

There are various other possible methods, but much less practical:

- split DHCP domain using DHCP snooping on the switches; route between subnets on the routers
- join IP subnets but use specific default gateways (via DHCP or static) to load balance WAN on an end-node basis
- join IP subnets with single/dual default gateways and use policy-based routing between the routers to load balance WAN on an end-node or protocol basis